# How can you mark an item by index if it is in list of lists?

Tags: list, indexing

I know this sounds like a basic question, but I must have either phrased it wrongly or simply no such answer exists: So: I operate on a list of lists (e.g. [[a1,b1,c1],[a1,b1,d1]]) and select each list individually by "for" loop ( for i in range(len(listA)): ) and need to check only the 2nd item in each sublist. My workaround is to mark a variable to each sublist, so it works like this:

```
for i in range(len(listA)):
 j = listA[i]
 if j[1] == ...:
...
```

I am not sure how much of the memory does allocating the pointer "j" require, but I think I could save time by not using it. Just need to know how exactly. Something like:

```
if listA[i][1] == ...
```

doesn't work and raises an error. Is there a proper syntax or do I need to use the workaround?

Comment: You should tag this with the language you're using...Python?

Comment: `listA[i][1]` is exactly the same as `j[1]`. Also you can just do `for j in listA:` instead.